# Refreshing $scope from inside a $scope.function()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First of all, I'm sorry if the post is too long. Also, just in case this somehow interferes with the answers you may give me, I'm not defining my controller in the usual way. Instead, I follow http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html, and do:

```
var game_1 = function($scope){
  var _this = this;
  //some code
  $scope.someFunction = function() {
    _this.someFunction() ;
  } ;
} ;
game1.prototype.someFunction = function() {
  //some code
} ;
game_1.$inject = ['$scope'] ;
app.controller('game_1', game_1) ;
```

In my HTML, I have an object with the attribute `ng-show="checkRare"`. Now, I have a set of functions that work kind of like a matryoshka doll:

Defined inside the controller:

```
this.promptElement = function(message) {
    var input = prompt(message) ;
    if ( input === null ) {
        this.resetCell(this.cellIJ) ;
        return false ;
    } else if ( input === '' ) {
        this.resetCell(this.cellIJ) ;
        return '' ;
    } else {
        return input.toUpperCase() ;
    }
} ;
//some more code
$scope.function1 = function(i,j,F) {
    _this.function1(i,j,F) ;
} ;
$scope.function2A = function(j) {
    _this.function2A(j) ;
} ;
$scope.function2B = function(i,F) {
    _this.function2B(i,F) ;
} ;
$scope.function3A = function() {
    _this.function3A() ;
} ;
$scope.function3B = function() {
    _this.function3B() ;
} ;
$scope.function4 = function() {
    $scope.checkRare = true ; //THE PROBLEM LIES HERE
    _this.function4() ;
} ;
```

And outside, I have:

```
game_1.prototype.function1 = function(i,j,F) {
    //some code 
    this.inputElement = this.promptElement('Enter element name') ;
    //some more code
} ;
game_1.prototype.function2A = function(j) {
    //some code
    for ( var i = 1 ; i < 8 ; i++ ) {
        this.function1(i,j) ;
        if ( this.inputElement === false ) { return ; }
    }
} ;
game_1.prototype.function2B = function(i,F) {
    //some code
    for ( var j = j0 ; j < jF ; j++ ) {
        this.function1(i,j,F) ;
        if ( this.inputElement === false ) { return ; }
    }
} ;
game_1.prototype.function3A = function() {
    //some code
    for ( var j = 1 ; j < 19 ; j ++ ) {
        this.function2A(j) ;
        if ( this.inputElement === false ) { return ; }
    }
} ;
game_1.prototype.function3B = function() {
    //some code
    for ( var i = 6 ; i < 8 ; i++ ) {
        this.function2B(i,true) ;
        if ( this.inputElement === false ) { return ; }
    }
} ;
game_1.prototype.function4 = function() {
    //some code
    this.function3A() ;
    if ( this.inputElement === false ) { return ; }
    this.function3B() ;
} ;
```

However, as someone suggested in another question I asked, the `$scope` is not going to refresh until the whole function has finished, so I won't be able to see the effects of `$scope.checkRare = true` until the end. In order for it to be the first thing that happens, I've tried using `$scope.$apply`, but I get the error `$apply already in progress` (which, by the way, I also get sometimes randomly). I've also tried using `$timeout` and a '`safeApply`' approach (https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js), but neither one worked.

So, any ideas on how to see the result of `$scope.checkRare = true` before the rest of the function runs its course? And, as a secondary question, could someone tell me why I sometimes get the `$apply already in progress` even when I'm not explictly using `$scope.$apply`?

Thanks in advance! And again, sorry for the long post! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I can accurately answer your question about `$apply` without a full working example. There are a number of factors that can trigger the error you mentioned.

Comment: Here, I made a fiddle (hope I made it right): https://jsfiddle.net/MarioMG/7zeae1eu/3/ Still some bugs I have to take care of, but that's basically it.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the error. Do you have steps for triggering it?

Comment: No, it happens randomly when pushing the "Ask whole table" button and either hitting Esc or entering "hydrogen". Sometimes I get it the first time, other times I have to play around before I get it, and even others I don't get it at all. It could even have disappeared with the `$timeout` bit and I will never know for sure!

Comment: I've played several times now and haven't triggered it yet. Maybe adding the `$timeout` bit took care of it? Thanks anyway, you were a great help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not fully understand your question, but I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
...
$scope.doSomething = function(){
  $scope.checkRare = true;
  $timeout(function(){
    // check for results of setting $scope.checkRare
  });
}
...
```

To understand why this works, it helps to understand the [JavaScript Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). In short, the DOM doesn't get updated until the end of an Event Loop iteration. Each iteration through the loop doesn't end until the JavaScript engine has run out of code to execute. When you put code into a timeout callback (with no delay), you are essentially telling the JavaScript engine to run that callback in the next iteration of the loop (thus allowing the DOM to be updated before the callback is run).

Comment: That was it! So many thanks! I had it wrong, I thought I had to wrap the `$scope.checkRare = true` bit inside the `$timeout` instead of the rest of the function. Now that I've done it like you say, it all works! :D